# How to type the less-than character in a Windows app inside a Parallels VM on a Craft keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard, parallels, macos-catalina

I have a new MacBook Pro 16" with macOS Catalina and Parallels Desktop 15 (with a Windows 10 German VM) on it and a Logitech Craft keyboard (German layout) connected to the MacBook Pro via Bluetooth.

In a Mac app like e.g. Pages, when I type `<` (Less-than) on the **MacBook Pro keyboard** then I get a `<` (Less-than) character in the Pages document. And when I press the same `<` (Less-than) key on the **Craft keyboard**  then I get also the `<` (Less-than) character in the Pages document.

**BUT**: When I press the `<` (Less-than) key on the **Craft keyboard** in a **Windows app** (e.g. Notepad) inside the Parallels Windows 10 VM then I get: NOTHING! (Only when I press the `<` (Less-than) key TWICE on the **Craft keyboard** then I get a double Circumflex character: `ˆˆ`).

So how can I get the `<` (Less-than) character in a Windows app inside the Parallels VM by pressing the `<` (Less-than) key on the **Craft keyboard**?

Comment: Do you have Windows set to use an International layout of any kind? [Usually International English] Test if similar happens with the ' key or "

Comment: Windows in the Parallels VM has German language. Also the Craft keyboard has a German layout.

Comment: Hello. I've let myself remove some excess formatting from your question. Backticks are meant to be used for code and literal characters (like `<` in your question). I've removed them from program names and I think the question is more readable now. If you don't think so, feel free to rollback the edit.

Comment: @gronostaj That is OK. It really looks better now.